# sum of two variables in different datasets

Tags: sas

sum of variable in two datasets a & b.
dataset a is

```
cc  spend
```

1   100

11  200

12  550

13  100

14  200

15  550

16  100

dataset b is 
cc spend

1   100

11  200

12  550

13  100

14  200

15  550

we have to create new dataset c variables are cc & spend.but spend is addition of spend in dataset a & dataset b.dataset c like this

cc spend

1 200

11 400

12 1100

13 200

like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by your output and sample data you provided, you want to sum `spend` kolumn from `a` data set with `spend` column from `b` data set but only when `cc` is matching.

```
data c;
   merge a(rename=(spend=spendA)) b(rename=(spend=spendB));
   by cc;

   spend = spendA + spendB

   drop spendA spendB;
run;
```

Please remember that in this case both of your data sets shoul be sorted by `cc`.

Comment: data append occur code you write but we need addition of spend column in dataset a & spend column in dataset b

Comment: @fl0r3k you wrote set instead of merge